# Ruby OpenSSL: convert p7b to crt?

Tags: ruby, ssl, openssl

I'm working on a program that, among other things, downloads a client ssl certificate from Digicert. Their API is only able to provide client certificates in `.p7b` format right now, and I have the following shell command to convert it:

`openssl pkcs7 -in certificate.p7b -print_certs -out certificate.crt`

I was hoping to find a way to accomplish this using Ruby's `OpenSSL` but the API documentation is pretty much just a bunch of method names. I've found this, though: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/PKCS7.html

Does anyone know if what I'm trying to do is possible using `OpenSSL` rather than shelling out?